# Magento 2 GET API requests displays 404

Tags: nginx, magento2

Doing a simple GET request shows a 404 response on our Magento 2.4.1

`https://domain/rest/V1/integration/admin/token?password=REDACTED&username=admin' --header 'Content-Type: application/json'`

> {"message":"Request does not match any route.","trace":null}

We are trying to do a get requests for an auth token from a third party email service and it's not working.

We are running ubuntu 20 + Nginx

Any conf settings we should be looking at?

Comment: did you find any solution to this ?